# Problemas con http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

Tags: android, c#, xml, visual-studio-2015, xamarin

Actualmente me estoy adentrando a la programación *Android con Visual Studio v3* y *Xamarín v4.3*.

El proyecto que estoy creando, es hacer un *layout* de inicio de sesión, pero tengo varios problemas con el `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`, ya que en algunas líneas del *XML*, me indica que no se han definidos los atributos.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema para poder entenderlo y en un futuro, poder solucionarlos con los demás proyectos que vaya a crear?

Código:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    //...
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" //El error es aquí.
        //...
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error:

> No se ha declarado el atributo `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_centerInParent`.

[image: Actualizado - Esta es la imagen del xml, donde se muestra el mismo error con el atributo schema.android.com]

Comment: Prueba a mirar que version del jdk estas usando en `Opciones/xamarin`. Debería ser jdk_1.8

Comment: Aunque el warning es posible que no desaparezca, ya que es un error del IntelliSense, pero deberia compilar correctamente

Comment: Añade el xml del layout completo

Comment: @MarcGV he añadido el archivo xml, donde también se muestra un sin fin de atributos no declarados, lo cual genera problemas con el axml, cuando hago referencia al xml....